# g++ + strncat: might overflow destination buffer

Tags: c++, c, g++, warnings, strcat

I need to include an C function in my C++ program, when compiling the Code with g++ I get the following warning:

```
In function ‘char* strncat(char*, const char*, size_t)’,
    inlined from ‘int get_usage(pid_t, pstat*)’ at src/getusage.c:24:
/usr/include/bits/string3.h:154: warning: call to
char* __builtin___strncat_chk(char*, const char*, long unsigned int,
long unsigned int) might overflow destination buffer
```

Code:

```
int pidof(const char* process_name){
char cmd[50] ="pidof ";
strncat(cmd, process_name, sizeof(cmd) - strlen(cmd) -1); 
[..]
```

How do I get rid of this warning?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please look around the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: ouh, stupid mistake :) I misread the error msg, the error were on another strncat use where I only passed the size of the buffer as size parameter => fixed :)

Comment: You should use std::string. They are easier to use. Have built in support for concatenation and they are also safer to use.

Comment: yes, If the function should only be used in c++ I had used std::string

Answer (score 1):

Your code is safe (I think), but the `strncat()` function is only safe to use if you know the length of:

1. the buffer
2. the material already in the buffer

If you also know the length of the material to be added and it is shorter than the space available, you can simply use `memmove()`; if it is longer, should you report that you're truncating it; if you don't know the length of the material to be added, maybe you should (so you can report that you're truncating something), but if that's inconvenient, then you can still use `memmove()` and add a null at the end of the buffer to ensure null termination.

Answer (score 1):

From a comment posted:

> the error were on another strncat use where I only passed the size of the buffer as size parameter => fixed

[`strlcat()`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/~checkout~/src/lib/libc/string/strlcat.c) presents a more straightforward interface to the kind of concatenation you're performing - designed to prevent exactly this type of error (forgetting to account for the length of the string already in the buffer).

If your toolchain doesn't have it, the OpenBSD version has a pretty liberal license, and if you're unable to incorporate that for whatever reason, it's a pretty simple function to implement yourself (just make sure to test the boundary conditions if you go this route). Do this once, and you can avoid bugs caused by improper use of `strncat()` forever. The types of bugs you might run into with improper use of `strlcat()` are likely to be less severe (forgetting to check for truncation is usually less of a problem than buffer overruns).